# Why has it shown pdo undefined?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, undefined

I have a script for db connection that is

```
<?php

//$dsn ='mysql:dbname=medicare;host=localhost';
$me = "root";
$password ="";

try{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=medicare',$me,$password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo"Error!:".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
die();


}

?>
```

then i have a function to add data in db_operations class that is

```
public static  function insert_admin($name,$pass){
// require_once("/connect.php");
$security = "?..H@Si./n/?";
$pass = md5($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT).$security;
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin(username,password)  VALUES(:username,:password)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); (line 79)
$stmt->bindParam(':username',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$pdo = null;


}
```

But it has shown

> Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\medicare\Model\class_db_operations.php on line 79
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\medicare\Model\class_db_operations.php on line 79
>   someone please help.

Comment: You need to pass the variable `$pdo` into your function if you want to be able to use it there.

Comment: would you please help me a bit more with more clear hints?

Comment: you should require your connection file:require_once(__CONNECTION_FILE_);

Comment: i did that by require_onec("filepath"); @okante

Comment: hum, that's you are in a function the variabe isn't defined either use global $pdo; in your function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$pdo` defined when `$pdo->prepare()` is called, you need to pass it as an argument or to make it available in the object as a property and set it with another method.

Comment: Would you suggest me a helpful link or example that will make clear this concept to me?

Comment: I haven't found it in the PHP basics, but it's quite simple : you can't use a variable in a function if it hasn't been defined in that function, either in the code itself or passed as an argument, except if you access it from the properties if the function is an object method or by using the keyword `global` if the variable is defined in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static  function insert_admin($name,$pass){
// require_once("/connect.php");
global $pdo;
$security = "?..H@Si./n/?";
$pass = md5($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT).$security;
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin(username,password)  VALUES(:username,:password)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); (line 79)
$stmt->bindParam(':username',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$pdo = null;


}
```

why are you setting $pdo to null at the end?